# Perl6: getc in raw mode

Tags: perl, terminal, raku, getc

I am using the Perl 6 module [Term::termios](https://github.com/krunen/term-termios/).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6
use v6;
use Term::termios;

my $saved_termios := Term::termios.new(fd => 1).getattr;
my $termios := Term::termios.new(fd => 1).getattr;
$termios.makeraw;
$termios.setattr(:DRAIN);

loop {
   my $c = $*IN.getc;
   print "got: " ~ $c.ord ~ "\r\n";
   last if $c eq 'q';
}

$saved_termios.setattr(:DRAIN);
```

When I run this script and press the keys <kbd>up-arrow</kbd>, <kbd>down-arrow</kbd>, <kbd>right-arrow</kbd>, <kbd>left-arrow</kbd> and <kbd>q</kbd> this is the output:

```
#after arrow-up:
got: 27
got: 91

#after arrow-down:
got: 65
got: 27
got: 91

#after arrow-right:
got: 66
got: 27
got: 91

#after arrow-left:
got: 67
got: 27
got: 91

#after q:
got: 68

#after another q:
got: 113
```

But I would have expected:

```
#after arrow-up:
got: 27
got: 91
got: 65

#after arrow-down:
got: 27
got: 91
got: 66

#after arrow-right:
got: 27
got: 91
got: 67

#after arrow-left:
got: 27
got: 91
got: 68

#after q:
got: 113
```

How do I have to modify the script to get the desired output?

Comment: Instead of `$*IN.getc`, have you tried using `$*IN.read(1)` (and modifying your code to take a Buf instead of a String)?

Comment: @bb94: With `read()` it worked. Could you change your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `my $c = $*IN.getc;` with `my $c = $*IN.read(1);` and change the rest of your code to handle a buffer instead of a string.